# python string formatting in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, underscore.js

Is there a better way to do this?  I'm using the underscore js lib here, which is where the _. comes from.  I'm used to this sort of procedure to format strings in python and i'd like something simple for javascript without doing + + + + all the time.  This works, but it feels like i reinvented the wheel.

```
function foo (iterable, string) {
  var s = iterable.shift();
  string = string.replace("%s",s);
  return _.isEmpty(iterable) ? string : foo(iterable,string);
};

foo(['sam','green','ham'],"%s likes %s eggs and %s.");
"sam likes green eggs and ham."
```

Comment: thanks for the input. both seem really cool, i'll have to check them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out the [sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) lib, specifically vsprintf.

```
vsprintf('The first 4 letters of the english alphabet are: %s, %s, %s and %s', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
```